# How to store class with sub class by Google Cloud Datastore JSON API?

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-datastore

For storing into *GCD*, I want to use [Google Cloud Datastore JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/) but I couldn't write correct `Json` request body for object with another class member. Consider I have `2` classes :

```
public class Foo {
    private String id;
    private Bar bar;
    // getter and setter...
}

public class Bar {
    private String name;
    private String pass;
    // getter and setter...
}
```

Then I create an object of `Foo` class that contain an object of `Bar` class.
So I want to insert this object to Cloud Datastore. I wrote this request body :

```
{
  "transaction":"some bytes",
  "mutation":{
    "insert":[
      {
        "key":{
          "partitionId":{
            "datasetId":"s~my-dataset-id"
          },
          "path":[
            {
              "kind":"Foo",
              "name":"id"
            }
          ]
        },
        "properties":{
          "bar":{
            "entityValue":{
              "name":{
                "stringValue":"Jack"
              },
              "pass":{
                "stringValue":"1234"
              }
            },
            "indexed":false
          },
          "id":{
            "stringValue":"id"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then all fields except `bar` will save to cloud datastore. I used "entityValue" but it seems that I should include the entire entity structure (thanks Adam for mention it). But I don't need it as another entity and obviously I shouldn't use "entityValue".
So how should I change the request body to insert such an object?

By the way, I can insert a `Bar` object (but not `Foo`) by following request :

```
   {
  "transaction":"some bytes",
  "mutation":{
    "insert":[
      {
        "key":{
          "partitionId":{
            "datasetId":"s~my-project-id"
          },
          "path":[
            {
              "kind":"Bar",
              "name":"John"
            }
          ]
        },
        "properties":{
          "pass":{
            "stringValue":"1234"
          },
          "name":{
            "stringValue":"John"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the related link : [Related link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/commit)

Comment: Your request looks correct. Are you getting an error message when you execute it?

Comment: When I try to store objects of the Foo class, nothing saved for the embedded Bar object.

Comment: How are you retrieving the Bar object?

Comment: I checked  on the google cloud datastore (https://console.developers.google.com/project/my-project-id/datastore/query) and other fields have value, but Bar object has no value.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot (you can send it to the email address on my profile)? When I try to reproduce this, I see the entity property with a message "Editing not supported for this type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may include `Bar` as an `entityValue`. This value looks like a normal Entity, but it doesn't need to have a key. This entity value does **not** need to exist separately in the Datastore.

For example:

```
{
  "mutation":{
    "insert":[
      {
        "key":{
          "path":[
            {
              "kind":"Foo",
              "name":"id"
            }
          ]
        },
        "properties":{
          "bar":{
            "entityValue":{
              "properties": {
                "name":{
                  "stringValue":"Jack"
                },
                "pass":{
                  "stringValue":"1234"
                }
              }
            },
            "indexed":false
          },
          "id":{
            "stringValue":"id"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "mode": "NON_TRANSACTIONAL"
}
```

Also as a side note, notice that the key for `Foo` here has left out the `partitionId`. This is the preferred thing to do, Datastore will fill in the correct `partitionId` for you.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. The `bar` objects saved as a JSON string, but I expect another form! Is there a way to query them?

Comment: Not yet -- You can't query on the individual fields because the `entityValue` is marked as `"indexed":false`. We are actively working on supporting indexed entity values. Then you'll be able to put it with `"indexed":true` and query for specific properties as `bar.name == "Jack"`. If you'd like to do that right now, you could store a separate property named "bar.name" for the properties you want to query by. When entity values support indexing you can update your code to use the indexed entity value properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the entire entity structure for 'entityValue' (including the "key" and "properties" fields). This is because you are referencing a separate entity in the Datastore and not just another data structure embedded in the current one. See:

**Datasets: Entity Format**
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/entity

The field 'entityValue": (Entity)' is a clue that you need to start from the beginning of this same entity representation for a new entity.

Comment: You are right. I thought that "entityValue" could handle embedded class object, but I don't need it as another Entity so how should I change my request body? (I will edit my question)

Comment: If all you want to do is store the subclass as an inline property of some entity, your best bet would be to manually serialize it and store the raw JSON as an embedded StringProperty. An embedded entity still needs a key, otherwise it's not an entity. It would be impossible to reference it in the datastore and distinguish it from just some property of some other entity (much like in C++, you can reference class 'Bar' on its own).